# Stereographic Projection of Riemann 2-sphere to produce 2D Mobius Transformation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am studying the Geometry of Stereographic Projections of Riemann Spheres to Create Mobius Transformations, in the context of "storing" the information of the entire complex plane within a finite surface.

A Stereographic Projection is basically a "hologram" of an n-sphere - we trace trace lines through it's coordinates and analyze the resulting pattern that is "projected" onto a surface.

A Riemann sphere is a special type of sphere where these coordinates are defined to have initial values (ie. when the sphere is unmanipulated) which satisfy this property: If you held a metaphorical "lamp" up at the top of the sphere (at its Azimuth), and traced the paths of the photons which intersect these points, you would get evenly distributed coordinates on the complex plane - essentially, you'd get its Cartesian representation.

Where this gets cool is when you manipulate the sphere, as in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z1fIsUNhO4, and project from the sphere's Azimuth lines which intersect these "preserved points" until they intersect the complex plane. This lets you do some cool non-Euclidian geometry, and leads into some even more advanced topics. Basically, it looks like this;

[image]

Essentially, while it is easy to draw this diagram in "standard position" (ie. for an unmanipulated Riemann sphere), the mathematics required to do this for manipulations of the sphere are at a level that TeX wasn't built for. Hence, my question of how to do this - in this case, using TikZ - for arbitrary manipulations of the Riemann sphere. This question is a special case of the general question: how can I get TikZ to make diagrams that are based on math that TeX isn't built for? The answer i came up with was to build an algorithm - using a programming language which *is* built for this kind of math - that generates the TikZ code for you.

As I mentioned, the initial diagram is easily within TeX's capabilities, so here's a MWE with that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% The resize box is to prevent the picture from going off the page. I have chosen the parameters \textwidth and !, with the intention of preserving its original dimensions.
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
% The common name for the top of a Riemann sphere - in this case a 2-sphere - is its "Azimuth."
\coordinate(Azimuth) at (0,8);
% The draw paths with thearrow heads are the coordinate axes.
\draw[black,-latex,thick] (0,-1) -- (0,9);
\draw[black,-latex,thick] (-10,0) -- (10,0);
% This circle is the Riemann 2-sphere. I have chosen a radius of two for reasons of accessibility.
\draw[] (0,6) circle [radius=2];
% This is the meat of the code. Here, we project equidistant points on the x-axis onto the Riemann 2-sphere. This basically "stores" all the information on the x-axis in a finite space. In 3D, this concept allows us to map the entire complex plane onto a unit-sphere - a useful tool in Complex Analysis.

% The points on the 2-sphere through which these lines intersect are preserved when the 2-sphere later undergoes geometric manipulations, such as rotations and translations. We can manipulate the Riemann sphere and then reproject - from its Azimuth - lines which intersect all of these "stored" points to create one-to-one re-representations of the x-axis. This is called a Conformal Transformation - more specifically, a Mobius Transformation.

% These manipulations appear quite difficult to achieve in plain LaTeX, due to their heavy-duty arithmetic nature.
\foreach \x in {-10,-9,...,10}{
\draw[] (\x,0) -- (Azimuth);}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying my best, man. I'll update the question. Pretty much, I wanted to do this in 3D, but found no resources to do it here or elsewhere. So I'm trying to fill that gap.

Comment: No - this site is not just "a library of knowledge". There are many different knowledge sites. This one is specific a Question and Answer page. Please see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour . It is never a problem to ask a question and answer it yourself. (I feel that is especially true, if it contributes to the community). Some "bureaucratic technicality" has to be maintained - so please delete your comment about "it isn't much of a question" and "bureaucratic technicality".

Comment: If you say so, @hpekristiansen. My suggestion in turn would be to put more emphasis on the *constructive* aspects of your criticisms (not just you, but people on this site in general). Not everyone appreciates "having the book thrown at them" for every minor mistake. This is why I try to be extra nice to the new people - because this site can be alienating to people who aren't PHD certified TeX experts.

Comment: And besides, you don't know where I come from or what my life experiences are. If you took the time to get to know even a little bit about me, I think you'd find that I have a *lot* of redeeming qualities.

Comment: Can you provide code for the bit you say is easy and explain what you are trying to do in a more accessible way? I don't even know what `the inverse stereographic projection of x-axis onto the circle` means, so it is certainly not easy for me! Nor do I know what `reprojecting from the circle's azimuth onto the x-axis through the rotated points) for rotations of the Riemann circle` should look like. As far as I'm concerned Riemann is the *other* kind of calculus i.e. the one I didn't learn and a couple of vaguely remembered disjointed facts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @cfr, I can see how this would be inaccessible for someone without specific experience in Stereographic Projections of Riemann Spheres to produce Mobius Transformations. I will consult my resources, so I can write up an elaboration which conveys the necessary details. I'm always happy to receive constructive criticism - especially if it can lead to an easier experience for others in the future.

Comment: @Pseudonym123 Thanks. It may also make your question more useful because similar problems may crop up in other cases. A more accessible question will allow other people facing those problems to figure out if your question/answers might be helpful.

Comment: @cfr I reworked the question and answer completely, paying close attention to the details. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve this post. Thanks again

Comment: @Pseudonym123 That makes a *lot* more sense now, so thank-you. In revising your question, you do seem to have lost the question, though, so perhaps you could add that back at the end? I.e. which question is your answer a solution to?

Comment: @cfr, Thank you for pointing that out - silly me. I will think about a good way to phrase this and update the question.

Comment: @cfr, cool! That should do it.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for the implementation of this capability in LaTeX is to use external software to "write the code for you." Essentially, I utilized the computer arithmetic capabilities - as well as the algorithmic capabilities - of the Python programming language to do this.

Below you can see my implementation (ie. in the code block).

It will be useful to future readers to see some of the mathematics associated with this, so I will include some of that too.

I created this figure to help me figure out how to rotate the lines through a  non-origin point. Below it is the corresponding mathematics.

[image]
[image]

I needed this diagram to help deduce the general formula for every line which intersects the n-sphere's Azimuth (except for when x=0 for reasons of domain restriction). Again, below it is the corresponding mathematics.

[image]
[image]

Though it turned out to be redundant in the end, this picture offered insights into the piece-wise nature of the sphere when defines as a function. See the math below.

[image]
[image]

This is another diagram I drew. With regard to its corresponding mathematics, I believe it is possible that I may have made a mistake somewhere - so be careful, and think for yourself.

[image]
[image]

The final goal of this operation - which will be in a post of mine in the near future will be based on this concept in 3D. My implementation will probably use Asymptote, but here's a concept drawing using TikZ:

[image]

And now to the meat; this is the product in two dimensions, along with the code you can use to generate each frame. I am looking forward to implementing this in 3D - this has been quite some fun to work on.

[image]

This is accomplishable with Python, using a process similar to the algorithm I developed below:

```
import numpy as np
r, L, linspace_amount=2.0, 8.0, 38
def x_input_function(x_input):
    return (2*x_input*r*np.abs((L**2)/(x_input**2+L**2))**(1/2))/np.abs(x_input**2+L**2)**(1/2)
x_input_list = [x_input_function(x_input) for x_input in np.linspace(-10,10,linspace_amount)]
def y_input_function_upper(x_input):
    return (np.abs(r**2-x_input**2)**(1/2)+L-r)
def y_input_function_lower(x_input):
    return (-np.abs(r**2-x_input**2)**(1/2)+L-r)
y_input_list = [y_input_function_upper(x_input) for x_input in x_input_list[:int(0.1*linspace_amount)]]
y_input_list.extend([y_input_function_lower(x_input) for x_input in x_input_list[int(0.1*linspace_amount):int(0.9*linspace_amount)]])
y_input_list.extend([y_input_function_upper(x_input) for x_input in x_input_list[int(0.9*linspace_amount):]])
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372480/rotate-point-about-another-point-in-degrees-python
import math
def rotate_x(x,y,theta): #rotate x,y around xo,yo by theta (rad)
    xr=math.cos(theta)*(x-0)-math.sin(theta)*(y-(L-r)) + 0
    return xr
def rotate_y(y,x,theta):
    yr=math.sin(theta)*(x-0)+math.cos(theta)*(y-(L-r))  + (L-r)
    return yr
rotated_x_list = []
rotated_y_list = []
def rotate(angle):
    global rotated_x_list,rotated_y_list
    rotated_x_list.clear()
    rotated_y_list.clear()
    for pos in range(len(x_input_list)):
        rotated_x_list.append(rotate_x(x_input_list[pos], y_input_list[pos],angle))
        rotated_y_list.append(rotate_y(y_input_list[pos], x_input_list[pos],angle))
start= r'''
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\clip[] (-10,-1) rectangle (10,9);
\draw[black,-latex,thick] (0,-1) -- (0,9); % y-axis
\draw[black,-latex,thick] (-10,0) -- (10,0); % x-axis
\draw[] (0,6) circle [radius=2];
'''
end = r'''
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
'''
def draw_path(x,y):
    if np.abs((-L*x)/(y-L)) < 40:
        return r'''\draw[] (0,8) -- ({},0);
\fill[] ({},{}) circle [radius=0.08];
'''.format((-L*x)/(y-L),x,y)
    else:
        return r'''\draw[] (0,8) -- (0,0);
'''
def make_tikz_code():
    string = r''
    string += start
    for pos in range(len(x_input_list)):
        try:
            string += draw_path(rotated_x_list[pos], rotated_y_list[pos])
        except:
            pass
    string += end
    return string
rotate(-10*np.pi/180)
print(make_tikz_code())
```

Comment: Since you were interested, this is what I got so far; will be working on getting this to work in 3D (in Asymptote) next! @Anna

Comment: So you're using Ti*k*Z to generate each frame based on calculations done with python? Have I got that right?

Comment: That is 100% correct! The next step is to do this in 3D with Asymptote.